# jersey-spring3 instantiating Spring-managed bean (null!)

Tags: spring, rest, dependency-injection, jersey, jersey-2.0

I first want to point out that this is by and large the biggest problem in terms of time wasted that I have ever dealt with in my career.  (Over two days straight now with essentially 0 progress.)  Every single "work-around" or "solution" I have attempted hasn't worked, so I am blocked and pretty desperate for some assistance.

The problem in a nutshell is that Jersey/HK2 seems to always instantiate my Spring-managed beans AFTER they have already been instantiated by Spring, which tells me that [jersey-spring3](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html) is not doing its job, or at least not with my current setup (or any of the ~50 permutations of setups I have tried thus far.)

**Note that when I use an empty constructor, those resource fields are null at run-time.**

I do not understand why my current setup doesn't work as I am essentially [copying this online example](https://github.com/ivarconr/jersey2-spring3-webapp/)

Any help is more than appreciated!!

## Configuration

**- - - - - pom.xml - - - - -**

```
<!-- ... -->

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring Dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- / Spring Dependencies -->

    <!-- API dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>${gson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- / API dependencies -->

    <!-- ... -->

</dependencies>

<!-- ... -->

<properties>

    <!-- ... -->

    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>

    <jersey.version>2.4.1</jersey.version>

    <gson.version>2.2.4</gson.version>

    <!-- ... -->

</properties>

<!-- ... -->
```

**- - - - - web.xml - - - - -**

```
<web-app>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- ... -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>fubar.rest.FubarJerseyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- ... -->

</web-app>
```

**- - - - - beans.xml (Context Configuration) - - - - -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<!-- ... -->

<!-- beans-outbound-api has configuration for spring-jersey3 to work properly -->
<import resource="beans-api.xml" />

</beans>
```

**- - - - - beans-api.xml - - - - -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Services -->

    <bean id="locationServiceV1" class="fubar.rest.v1.services.location.impl.LocationServiceV1" />
    <bean id="locationServiceV2" class="fubar.rest.v2.services.location.impl.LocationServiceV2" />

    <bean id="viewServiceV1" class="fubar.rest.v1.services.view.impl.ViewServiceV1" />
    <bean id="viewServiceV2" class="fubar.rest.v2.services.view.impl.ViewServiceV2" />

    <!-- Resources -->

    <bean class="fubar.rest.resources.location.impl.LocationResource">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="locationServiceV1" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="locationServiceV2" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="fubar.rest.resources.view.impl.ViewResource">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="viewServiceV1" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="viewServiceV2" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

## Code

**- - - - - Resource (JAX-RS) - - - - -**

```
@Path(RESTLocationResourceV1.PathFields.PATH_ROOT)
@Produces({V1_JSON, APPLICATION_JSON})
public class LocationResource
    extends ResourceBase<LocationResource, ILocationServiceV1, ILocationServiceV2> {

  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LocationResource.class);

  @Inject
  public LocationResource(final LocationServiceV1 v1Loc, final LocationServiceV2 v2Loc) {
    super(v1Loc, v2Loc);
    logger.info(format(Messages.INF_INSTANTIATED, "LocationResource"));
  }

  @GET
  @Path(PathFields.SUBPATH_LIST)
  public LocationListV1 listV1(@HeaderParam(HEADER_API_KEY) String apiKey)
      throws ApplicationException {
    // Implementation
  }

  @GET
  @Path(PathFields.SUBPATH_SEARCH)
  public LocationListV1 searchV1(@HeaderParam(HEADER_API_KEY) String apiKey,
      @QueryParam(QueryFields.QUERY) String likeText) throws ApplicationException {
    // Implementation
  }
}
```

**- - - - - Service (Spring Bean) - - - - -**

```
public class LocationServiceV1 extends ServiceBaseV1<LocationBean, LocationV1, LocationListV1>
    implements
      ILocationServiceV1 {

  @Autowired
  private LocationDao daoLoc;

  public LocationServiceV1() {
    super(new LocationBeanToJsonTranslatorV1());
  }

  @Override
  public LocationListV1 listV1() throws ApplicationException {
    // Implementation
  }

  @Override
  public LocationListV1 searchV1(String likeText) throws ApplicationException {
    // Implementation
  }
}
```

*(Essentially the same for version 2)*

**- - - - - Application (Jersey) - - - - -**

```
public class FubarJerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

  private static final class Messages {
    static final String INF_STARTING_APPLICATION = "Starting %s!";
  }

  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FubarJerseyApplication.class);

  public FubarJerseyApplication() {
    packages("fubar.rest");
    logger.info(format(Messages.INF_STARTING_APPLICATION, this.getClass().getName()));
  }
}
```

## Invocation (Client)

```
curl http://my-ip-address/fubar/api/location/list
```

*(500 Internal Server Error)*

## Error (Server)

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object
available for injection at Injectee(requiredType=LocationServiceV1,parent=
LocationResource,qualifiers={}),position=0,optional=false,self=false,
unqualified=null,344016971)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:74)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:208)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:225)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:329)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:158)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2350)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:612)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:597)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:173)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:103)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:128)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:110)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:65)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:250)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:983)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:361)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at fubar.server.springframework.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:44)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at fubar.server.springframework.loader.ContextLoaderHttpInterceptor$LoaderState.filter(ContextLoaderHttpInterceptor.java:75)
at fubar.server.springframework.loader.ContextLoaderHttpInterceptor$StartedState.filter(ContextLoaderHttpInterceptor.java:120)
at fubar.server.springframework.loader.ContextLoaderHttpInterceptor.doFilter(ContextLoaderHttpInterceptor.java:62)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:311)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

## API Log

```
Dec 10, 2013 13:36:28 INFO  [main] fubar.rest.FubarJerseyApplication
     - Starting fubar.rest.FubarJerseyApplication!
Dec 10, 2013 13:38:06 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] resources.location.impl.LocationResource
     - LocationResource has been instantiated
Dec 10, 2013 13:38:06 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] resources.view.impl.ViewResource
     - ViewResource has been instantiated
```

---

Update -- found this:

## Catalina Log

```
Dec 10, 2013 1:36:42 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler initialize
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.4.1 2013-11-08 12:08:47...
Dec 10, 2013 1:36:43 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider initialize
SEVERE: Spring context lookup failed, skipping spring component provider initialization.
Dec 10, 2013 1:38:00 PM com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector inject
```

... so the ApplicationContext isn't found in [SpringComponentProvider#initialize](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/ext/spring3/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/spring/SpringComponentProvider.java#L82).

Comment: Welcome to the club! :( After my initial hurdles, I'm thinking of just ditching Jersey 2.7 and go with either Apache CXF or Spring MVC (which unfortunately isn't JAX-RS...). I guess in the meantime we should just stick with Jersey 1.x??

Comment: This post is very old but I have been told through the grapevine that the latest updates to jersey-spring3 solves this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a custom, asynchronous [ContextLoader](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html), so the interim solution required placing a total hack in the [Jersey-Spring3](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/ext/spring3) source to wait for the  application to initialize before the custom component provider initializes.

P.S. For any poor soul who finds themselves having to do something like this, make sure META-INF/settings contains the [SpringComponentProvider](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/ext/spring3/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/spring/SpringComponentProvider.java) configuration.

---

(2014-04-18) Elaborating for @Scott

Note that this is a *terrible* hack and I would only attempt such a thing as a last resort when all other attempts have failed, like in my case.  Also I would consult the Jersey mailing group about your problem before attempting anything like this.

That said... this is what I did to solve my problem:

- Literally copied the source code of spring-jersey3 into my application/server, modifying the header of every file with the appropriate tags as per the license;
- Created the following class --

===>

```
  /**
   * Hack class for RN-8979.
   *
   * @author ryan
   *
   */
  public class ContextLoadWaiter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ContextLoadWaiter.class);

    public void doWait() {

      try {
        while (ContextLoaderHttpInterceptor.isNotStarted()) {
          logger.info("Waiting for ContextLoader to start...");
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error("SpringComponentProvider was interrupted!");
      }
    }
  }
```

*Note that this is specific to *our* code-base as `ContextLoaderHttpInterceptor` is an http servlet where `isNotStarted` returns `true` if our custom `ContextLoader` (which happens to be asynchronous) is not yet loaded.*

The custom asynchronous `ContextLoader` was put in place sometime by somebody for some reason along the lines of allowing the UI to display a "loading" page while the server boots up.  (Probably not the correct way to add this UI "feature", but the code was there and the UI depended on it, so I had to deal with it...)

Since this part will not apply directly to you, the key thing is to debug through `SpringComponentProvider` (from [here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/ext/spring3/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/spring/SpringComponentProvider.java)) and look at the value of the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`.  If it is `null`, as it is in our case, then you need to figure out why it is `null` and wait on whatever `ContextLoader` you use to load before you initialize this component.

- Placed this hacky line in `SpringComponentProvider` --

==>

```
  ...

  private final ContextLoadWaiter waiter = new ContextLoadWaiter();

  ...

  @Override
  public void initialize(ServiceLocator locator) {

    waiter.doWait(); // Wait on our asynchronous context loader.

    this.locator = locator;

    if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) {
      LOGGER.fine("Context lookup started");
    }

    ...
```

- Created this file: `META-INF/services/org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.ComponentProvider` with the contents being the fully qualified classpath to the SpringComponentProvider, e.g. `com.company.server.nbi.rest.internal.jspring.SpringComponentProvider`
- Added the custom Jersey-spring3 package as a package to scan in the application; see below...

==>

```
/**
 * Application configuration.
 *
 * @author ryan
 *
 */
public class MyJerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

  private static final class Messages {
    static final String INF_STARTING_APPLICATION = "Starting %s!";
  }

  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyJerseyApplication.class);

  public MyJerseyApplication() {

    packages(
    /* Internal providers */
    "com.company.server.nbi.rest.providers",
    /* Internal filters */
    "com.company.server.nbi.rest.filters",
    /* Spring injection support */
    "com.company.server.nbi.rest.internal.jspring", // HERE!!!
    /* Json providers */
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json",
    /* Jackson exception mappers */
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base");

    /* Resources */
    register(ResourceA.class);
    register(ResourceB.class);
    register(ResourceC.class);

    /* Miscellaneous features */
    register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    register(LoggingFilter.class);

    logger.info(format(Messages.INF_STARTING_APPLICATION, this.getClass().getName()));
  }
}
```

That's "it".  Definitely not a solution to be proud of, but if you are in desperation mode like I was, it probably doesn't hurt to give it a shot.

Comment: Edited a mistake I made -- the file you need is called META-INF/services/org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.ComponentProvider

Comment: can i ask something, what does jersey spring give you? ability to inject Autowired spring beans? is there no other way to legally get them using spring api?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni As far as "Jersey Spring", yes... the ability to inject Autowired beans.  As far as Jersey itself... the company I worked at was using an ancient version of Spring at the time I started working on the project, and Jersey seemed a good alternative to a compatibility nightmare.

Answer (score 10):

What's loading first?  Spring or Jersey?  It could be that your Spring context isn't initialized when SpringComponentProvider calls `WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(sc);`.  Try using Spring's ContextLoaderListener so that Spring does its initialization right after the app is deployed.

I ran into a lot of the same issues that you're experiencing with the jersey-spring3 library.  It had problems finding my Spring ApplicationContext (looks like this is where you're stuck) and it blew up injecting setters that took a generic parameter as an argument.

If you get past the app context issue, I don't think what you have will work anyway.  You defined the ViewResource and LocationResource beans in XML.  From what I can tell, Jersey will only get the resource instance from Spring if the the resource class is annotated with @Component.  Take a look at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider, specifically `component.isAnnotationPresent(Component.class)`:

```
// detect JAX-RS classes that are also Spring @Components.
// register these with HK2 ServiceLocator to manage their lifecycle using Spring.
@Override
public boolean bind(Class<?> component, Set<Class<?>> providerContracts) {

    if (ctx == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if(component.isAnnotationPresent(Component.class)) {
        DynamicConfiguration c = Injections.getConfiguration(locator);
        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanNamesForType(component);
        if(beanNames == null || beanNames.length != 1) {
            LOGGER.severe(LocalizationMessages.NONE_OR_MULTIPLE_BEANS_AVAILABLE(component));
            return false;
        }
        String beanName = beanNames[0];

        ServiceBindingBuilder bb = Injections.newFactoryBinder(new SpringComponentProvider.SpringManagedBeanFactory(ctx, locator, beanName));
        bb.to(component);
        Injections.addBinding(bb, c);
        c.commit();

        LOGGER.config(LocalizationMessages.BEAN_REGISTERED(beanName));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

An unrelated issue was that we also wanted to move all of our JAX-RS annotations to interfaces.  Whenever I tried it, I got "Could not find a suitable constructor for com.foo.ResourceInterface".

In the end, I solved all of my issues by not using jersey-spring3 and rolling my own Jersey to Spring connector.  Here's what I did:

1. Configured all of my resources as regular Spring beans.  You can use XML if you want.
2. In my Application, I added bindings to the HK2 container to use a factory whenever it needs an instance of one of the resources.  My factory class simply returns the Spring managed instance of the resource.
3. Before the factory returns the Spring-managed bean, I use the Jersey/HK2 ServiceLocator to inject things that Jersey provides.  For example, anything annotated with @Context.

My javax.ws.rs.Application looks like this:

```
public class RestConfig extends ResourceConfig {
private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(RestConfig.class);


@Inject
public RestConfig(ServiceLocator locator) {
    super();
    // specific to my app. get your spring beans however you like
    Collection<Object> beans = BeanLocator.beansByAnnotation(RestResource.class);

    DynamicConfiguration c = Injections.getConfiguration(locator);


    for (Object bean : beans)
    {
                    // tell jersey to use a factory for any interface that the bean implements.  since your resources don't implement interfaces, 
                    // you'll want to do something a bit different here.
        for (Class<?> currentInterface : bean.getClass().getInterfaces())
        {
            if (log.isTraceEnabled())
                log.trace("binding " + currentInterface.getSimpleName() + " to Spring managed bean");

            ServiceBindingBuilder<Object> bb = Injections.newFactoryBinder(new StaticLookupFactory(locator, bean));
            bb.to(currentInterface);
                    Injections.addBinding(bb, c);
        }
    }

            // commit the changes to the HK2 container (don't skip this step!)
            c.commit();

    property("jersey.config.disableMoxyJson.server", true);
    packages("com.foo.web.rest");

    register(MoxyXmlFeature.class);
}


// a "factory" where the provide() method returns the spring managed bean
    // that was passed to the constructor.
private static class StaticLookupFactory implements Factory<Object> {

    private ServiceLocator locator;
    private Object bean;

    StaticLookupFactory(ServiceLocator locator, Object bean)
    {
        this.locator = locator;
        this.bean = bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object provide() {
                    // inject this annotated with @Context, @Inject, etc
        locator.inject(bean);
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(Object instance) {
    }

}
}
```

`BeanLocator` is a utility class that I wrote that makes it easy to grab bean instances using static methods when autowiring isn't available.  For example, when working outside of Spring managed beans.  Not too much going on there:

```
public static Collection<Object> beansByAnnotation(Class<? extends Annotation> annotation)
{
    return applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(annotation).values();
}
```

`RestResource` is also specific to our app.  It's a custom stereotype that works like @Component, @Service, etc:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Component
public @interface RestResource {
    String value() default "";
}
```

Note that Jersey allows you to register custom implementations of org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.ComponentProvider to manage the lifecycle of resources on your own.  I tried it but couldn't get it to recognize my implementation no matter what I did.

One other note... the `locator.inject(bean)` call that activates the Jersey dependency injection mechanism will processes anything marked with @Inject.  Use @Autowired within your classes or configure your beans with XML to avoid having both Spring and Jersey attempt to resolve values for things annotated with @Inject.

Comment: Thanks for your response -- I will look into what you did later. Just wanted to comment on "An unrelated issue was that we also wanted to move all of our JAX-RS annotations to interfaces. Whenever I tried it, I got "Could not find a suitable constructor for com.foo.ResourceInterface"." -- I was able to get around this by manually registering all of the providers and resources. When you register resources via package scanning, this error happens. (Definitely a Jersey bug...)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This saved me. I placed the ContextLoaderListener to be the first listener in the web.xml. This apparently had fixed the issue for me. But then I updated the servlet-api version in the web.xml from 2.5 to 3.0 and got the same issue again. I then also reordered the servlets in the web.xml so that a spring servlet (WSSpringServlet) was in the first position. Otherwise, some other libraries had caused the SpringComponentProvider to be initialized first.

Answer (score 1):

This is the message that is key to understanding the issue. It indicates that Spring is failing to initialise correctly:

```
SEVERE: Spring context lookup failed, skipping spring component provider initialization.
```

(On a side note: because Spring is failing to initialise, the only JSR-330 implementation to try and resolve the `@Inject` is HK2 - which is why you're seeing the other issue).

Anyway, the problem is likely that your container isn't performing a scan for the annotations that make all the `jersey-spring3` magic happen.

This behaviour is part of the Servlet 3.0 Specification (JSR-33, Section 1.6.2), so you should double check that your container supports this.

In the case of Tomcat - unless you're running Tomcat 7.0.29 or newer, you'll actually need to make sure that the Servlet version is specified in your web.xml.

[http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_7.0.29_(markt)](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_7.0.29_%28markt%29)

I hit this problem recently and it drove me nuts, and fixing the web.xml was easier than upgrading from Ubuntu/Precise!

Hope this helps!

Comment: WIN: I was also suffering from a subtle failure followed by a noisy failure. Your post focused me on the subtle one first -- thanks!

Comment: No worries, unfortunately it looks like Jetty doesn't even support servlet 3.0 scanning properly (if you're using that).

Dropwizard looks better and better by the day :)

Comment: [Dropwizard](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard) looks nice, thanks for pointing that out.