# NoSuchMethodError on Values.lazy (Jersey 2.5.1)

Tags: api, rest, tomcat, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am officially perplexed by this blocker.

I had upgraded Jersey from 2.4.1 to 2.5.1 because Jersey/Oracle fixed a package scanning bug that was affecting getting [Swagger](https://helloreverb.com/developers/swagger) working.  2.4.1 was working relatively "okay" after lots of hacks to integrate with our Spring-based server (spring-jersey3 was [not working at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506644/jersey-spring3-instantiating-spring-managed-bean-null).) Now since upgrading to 2.5.1 (and now, 2.6-SNAPSHOT), I receive the error below each time I make a request to anything matching the API URL pattern.

What I have done:

- Redeployed on a new, clean server (clean maven repository, clean tomcat, etc);
- Checked that the jar is the correct version (and even decompiled the "Value" class to ensure it was the one I see on GitHub that was updated ~2 months ago);
- Looked at all of the jars using [tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale) to look for class conflicts;
- Upgraded to 2.6-SNAPSHOT (noted above), building the [latest](https://github.com/jersey/jersey);
- Posted a [bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2394) (no response);

Help/work-arounds/debugging ideas much appreciated... don't even know what more I can do besides scrapping Swagger, a few days of work, and rolling back to 2.4.1

```
Feb 12, 2014 15:46:24 ERROR [TP-Processor6] [Catalina].[localhost].[/company
[Jersey REST Service] - Servlet.service() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw           
exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values.lazy(Lorg/glassfish/jersey/internal/util
collection/Value;)Lorg/glassfish/jersey/internal/util/collection/Value;
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.company.videoapp.server.springframework.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:44)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.company.videoapp.server.springframework.loader.ContextLoaderHttpInterceptor$LoaderState.filter(ContextLoaderHttpInterceptor.java:75)
at com.company.videoapp.server.springframework.loader.ContextLoaderHttpInterceptor$StartedState.filter(ContextLoaderHttpInterceptor.java:120)
at com.company.videoapp.server.springframework.loader.ContextLoaderHttpInterceptor.doFilter(ContextLoaderHttpInterceptor.java:62)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:311)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

---

## Update

I got rid of the ubiquitous `500` error, *but I still get that exception*. Here are some observations --

### 2.5.1 & 2.6-SNAPSHOT

Interfaces... inheritance... very buggy in 2.5.1+ (at least two regression bugs.)

My constant 500 errors were due to this, so after removing the interfaces I can *at least* hit a valid endpoint. Scenarios below:

#### Broken scenario #1 -- Implementing Resource Interface

```
@Path(MY_PATH)
@Produces(...)
@Consumes(...)
interface MyResource {
   ...
   @GET myResourceMethod();
}
```

.

```
public class MyAwesomeResource implements MyResource {
   ...
}
```

> *Sending a request to the above resource results in a `404` exception, which in turn results in a `500` for the client because of some unknown issue possibly related to the exception above.*

#### Broken scenario #2 -- Making interface public

```
@Path(MY_PATH)
@Produces(...)
@Consumes(...)
public interface MyResource {
   ...
   @GET myResourceMethod();
}
```

.

```
public class MyAwesomeResource implements MyResource {
   ...
}
```

> *Results in another `500` from an internal NoSuchMethodError exception (the one in the comment -- "Could not find a suitable constructor in MyResource.class") when issuing a request to the resource*

The exception posted in the original question is masking real exceptions (`404` becomes `500`... I have to remote debug to see the actual exception.)

Hope Jersey devs are paying attention to this.  Not cool.

Comment: Remote debugging... this looks like a double regression for Jersey -- inherited annotations are not working, and furthermore, interface annotations no longer work (`Feb 12, 2014 17:21:59 ERROR [TP-Processor3] [Catalina].[localhost].[/company].[Jersey REST Service] - Servlet.service() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in MyResourceInterface.class`) -- tested by changing the interface from public to default. Unfortunately Swagger does not support annotation inheritance, so these are conflicting issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on informations provided in [JERSEY-2394](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2394) your class-path contains these libraries:

```
rw-rr- 1 root root 94774 Feb 10 12:02 cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.3.2.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 341446 Feb 10 12:02 cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.3.2.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 20020 Feb 10 12:02 jackson-jaxrs-base-2.2.3.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 15243 Feb 10 12:02 jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.2.3.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 25985 Feb 10 12:02 jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.2.3.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 50034 Feb 10 12:02 jackson-module-jsonSchema-2.1.0.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 79309 Feb 10 12:02 javax.json-1.0.2.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 19754 Feb 10 12:02 javax.json-api-1.0.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 876610 Feb 10 12:02 jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 226915 Feb 10 12:02 jaxen-1.1.1.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 159742 Feb 10 14:02 jersey-client-2.5.1.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 700399 Feb 10 14:02 jersey-common-2.5.1.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 15684 Feb 10 14:02 jersey-container-servlet-2.5.1.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 52593 Feb 10 12:02 jersey-container-servlet-core-2.1.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 6412 Feb 10 14:02 jersey-media-json-processing-2.5.1.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 63067 Feb 10 12:02 jersey-media-multipart-2.1.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 828016 Feb 10 14:02 jersey-server-2.5.1.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 86540 Feb 10 12:02 json4s-ast_2.10-3.2.4.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 568890 Feb 10 12:02 json4s-core_2.10-3.2.4.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 74565 Feb 10 12:02 json4s-ext_2.10-3.2.4.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 39952 Feb 10 12:02 json4s-jackson_2.10-3.2.4.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 68734 Feb 10 12:02 json4s-native_2.10-3.2.4.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 7814 Feb 10 12:02 jsonp-jaxrs-1.0.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 121047 Feb 10 12:02 swagger-jaxrs_2.10-1.3.2.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 45719 Feb 10 12:02 swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10-1.3.2.jar
```

You have 2 Jersey jars with different version than 2.5.1 - `jersey-media-multipart-2.1.jar` and `jersey-container-servlet-core-2.1.jar`. The latter one causes the problem you have. Lines from the stacktrace correspond with the idea that 2.1 version of jersey servlet core is used instead of 2.5.1 (see [WebComponent](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.1/containers/jersey-servlet-core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/WebComponent.java#L346) from 2.1). The solution would be to remove the old jars.

Comment: Wow, I'm happy you noticed that but very disappointed I didn't.  Odd because everything in the pom references ${jersey.version} which is 2.6-SNAPSHOT.  Will see which dependency pulls this in -- thanks.

Comment: And the fix -- <dependency><groupId>com.wordnik</groupId><artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId><version>${swagger-jersey2.version}</version><exclusions><exclusion><groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId><artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId></exclusion></exclusions></dependency>