# Swagger ServletHandlerError

Tags: java, maven, jetty, swagger, jersey-2.0

I want to have a documentation for my REST-Calls, in a earlier Project I written it alone but now the Project is a bit bigger so I searched for a good framework. I found swagger.io. It looks very nice and the implementation looks very simple for the maven project. I set the dependency in the Path

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and configure the servlets of the web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>
        io.swagger.jaxrs.listing,
        package.rest
    </param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>io.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>api.version</param-name>
        <param-value>0.0.1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8080/rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I think I have done it but after a new Maven Install and start the Jetty Server, I called the url localhost:8080/rest/swagger.xaml or ../swagger.json there comes the following Exception:

```
2016-07-08 09:13:12.058:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:Error for /rest/swagger.json
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values.lazy(Lorg/glassfish/jersey/internal/util/collection/Value;)Lorg/glassfish/jersey/internal/util/collection/Value;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Do you can help me?

I tried the install guide if swagger.io also for Jersey 1.17.1 there comes no exception but also no result.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` above is stemming from having different versions of Jersey 2 jars in your classpath.

See [NoSuchMethodError on Values.lazy (Jersey 2.5.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742665/nosuchmethoderror-on-values-lazy-jersey-2-5-1/21743658) and https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2394 for more details.

Comment: I have only one dependency of Jersey in my two MavenProjects so I will have only one Jersey jar in my classpath or not?