# SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [abc] in context with path [/xyz] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException]

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, jersey

Developing rest web service with jersey, maven and spring. New to spring and maven. facing SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [abc] in context with path [/xyz] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] issue. when i invoke rest web service My response object is null.
Below is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ecable</groupId>
  <artifactId>ecableWS</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
        <jersey.version>2.2</jersey.version>
        <javax.servlet.version>2.3</javax.servlet.version>
        <spring.batch.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
        <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
                <version>6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.51</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.8.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-simple</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-declarative-linking</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
            </dependency> 
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>3.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
                <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
</dependencies>
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Below is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>xyz</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <!-- <servlet>
        <servlet-name>context</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1000</load-on-startup>
    </servlet> -->
  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>
          org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.ecable.endpoint</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1001</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And my responseObject is below with getters and setters

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "myresponse", propOrder = {
    "cityId",
    "cityDesc"
})
@Component
public class Myresponse {
```

And my endpoint is below

```
@Path("/fetch")
public class LoginWSEndPoint {
    @Autowired
    private Myresponse myresponse ;

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response responseMsg(){
        myresponse.setCityDesc("desc city");
        myresponse.setCityId(" city id");
        return Response.status(200).entity(loginResponse).build();

    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Please see the logs

```
Jul 03, 2015 12:34:05 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.AutowiredInjectResolver getBeanFromSpringContext
WARNING: No beans found. Resolution failed for type class com.objects.MyResponse.
Jul 03, 2015 12:34:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [abc] in context with path [/xyz] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ecable.endpoint.LoginWSEndPoint.responseMsg(LoginWSEndPoint.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:140)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:158)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:353)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:343)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:237)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:211)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:982)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:359)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Also please see my beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.objects" />
    <context:annotation-config />
</beans>
```

Comment: Most probably `Myresponse` is not injected. As to why this happens, maybe seeing the complete stacktrace could help tracking down what the problem is.

Comment: i have updated with the logs

Comment: The second line of the stacktrace is the culprit : `WARNING: No beans found. Resolution failed for type class com.objects.MyResponse.` Spring tried to resolve the bean, but it couldn't. Maybe you just have to configure your application so that the bean can be resolved.

Comment: i have updated rest-config.xml above. what is wrong with it? how to configure it?

Comment: maybe the empty `<context:annotation-config />` interferes with spring's deafult configuration. Try removing it (I'm sorry I can't point you straight to the problem, but since it is 99% a configuration issue, it is quite difficult to understand what's interfering)

Comment: Yes i removed it and checked. still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Javadoc for [`AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) it seems to me that there is nothing obviously wrong with your code. In order to try narrowing things down, try to put an explicit `Autowired` annotation on the default constructor of `Myresponse` and see what happens :

```
//...
public class Myresponse {
// ...

  @Autowired(required = true)
  public Myresponse() {}

// ...
}
```

Another possible issue could be this excerpt from the javadoc linked above :

> Note: A default AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor will be registered by the "context:annotation-config" and "context:component-scan" XML tags. Remove or turn off the default annotation configuration there if you intend to specify a custom AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bean definition

EDIT : it seems you're experiencing the same problem as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436388/trouble-autowiring-spring-dependencies-in-jersey-using-jersey-spring). The answer says that you have to provide the configuration for Spring via the `applicationContext.xml`, not `web.xml`. THat file also has to be put in the `WEB-INF` folder.