# Spring 4 + jersey integration @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, spring-data-neo4j

I tried a lot of things but it seems that my "searchservice" in my jersey ressource instantiate itself randomly. SearchService in SearchResource is almost always null.

As you can see I added spring-jersey dependency.

Here is my code :
SearchResource (jersey, try to instantiante searchService)

```
@Path("search")
@Component
public class SearchResource {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SearchResource.class);
    @Context
    private UriInfo context;
    @Autowired
    private SearchService searchService;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of SearchResource
     */
    public SearchResource() {
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of com.gehc.mpse.backend.ws.SearchResource
     * @param search
     * @param <error>
     * @param authors
     * @return an instance of java.lang.String
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response search(@QueryParam("query") String search, @QueryParam("authors") List<String> authors) {
        System.out.println("searchservice :" + searchService);
        Response res = searchService.searchQuery(search);
        return res;
    }

    public SearchService getSearchService() {
        return searchService;
    }

    public void setSearchService(SearchService searchService) {
        this.searchService = searchService;
    }
```

My class searchService :

```
@Component
public class SearchService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SearchService.class);
    @Autowired
    private IPublicationRepository repository;
    @Autowired
    private Neo4jTemplate template;
    private static final Integer PAGE_SIZE = 20;

    public SearchService() {
        LOGGER.debug("search service initialzed " + this);
    }

    public Response searchQuery(String query) {

        PageRequest request
                = new PageRequest(1, PAGE_SIZE);
        LOGGER.debug("repo : " + repository);
        Page<Publication> res = repository.findPublicationByTitle(query, request);
        //repository.query(query, null);
        return Response.ok().entity(res.getContent()).build();
    }

    public IPublicationRepository getRepository() {
        return repository;
    }

    public void setRepository(IPublicationRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public Neo4jTemplate getTemplate() {
        return template;
    }

    public void setTemplate(Neo4jTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

}
```

My pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>neo4j-cypher</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring [End] -->
    <!--neo4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end neo4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-java2wsdl</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>            
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
                <artifactId>hk2</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My web.xml :

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>PMSE</display-name>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:spring/context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Here is my code : SearchResource (jersey, try to instantiante searchService)

Note that Jersey won't instantiate your SearchService.  Because you have a `@Component` annotation on the resource, SearchService should be wired into SearchResource by Spring and Jersey should retrieve the SearchResource instance from Spring.

Is your Spring context being created twice (once by Jersey and once by Spring's ContextLoaderListener)?  Is the Spring context [fully initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506644/jersey-spring3-instantiating-spring-managed-bean-null) before Jersey starts?  Jersey looks for a Spring context and then attempts to [create one on its own](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/ext/spring3/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/spring/SpringComponentProvider.java#L98) (line 98) if it can't find one.

Jersey's Spring integration is somewhat difficult.  Your best bet is to set some breakpoints in [SpringComponentProvider](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/ext/spring3/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/spring/SpringComponentProvider.java) and [AutowiredInjectResolver](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/ext/spring3/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/spring/AutowiredInjectResolver.java) and then step through it in your debugger.  When debugging, you can set `suspend=y` so that nothing happens until you actually connect with the debugger.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/what-are-java-command-line-options-to-set-to-allow-jvm-to-be-remotely-debugged) for more details on the debug setup.

I'd also check the Jersey Jira for [Spring related issues](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2112?jql=project%20%3D%20JERSEY%20AND%20text%20~%20spring) and see if any of the open issues apply to you.